# Как в c# проверить является ли класс дата-классом?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Пишу программу для sql-скриптов, и мне необходимо провести проверку является ли класс дата классом. Как это можно сделать?

С помощью рефлексии я подключаю сборку/проект,

```
Assembly myLibrary = Assembly.LoadFile(@"путь");
        //прохожу по каждому типу в сборке 
        foreach(Type type in myLibrary.GetTypes())
        { //здесь нужно сделать проверку, что класс содержит только свойства }
```

Когда я использую

```
int count = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public).Count();
```

то он прибавляет и свойства. Как мне проверить содержатся ли только свойства в классе?

Comment: Что такое дата-класс?

Comment: Если класс наследуется от какого нибуть базового класса. то можно проверить. Тупо от Object то будите искать какой либо индиктор

Comment: Класс в котором содержатся только свойства?

Comment: Такого не бывает. По сути все объекты потомки Object в котором есть методы

Comment: Ну имеется ввиду, чтобы кроме наследуемых методов других не было. Только свойства.

Comment: тогда тут посмотрите https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethods?view=net-5.0

Comment: Рефлексией: `Type.GetMethods().Count()`. Вычесть методы, имеющиеся у `object`.

Comment: Если вы пишете что-то вроде ORM-библиотеки, то для идентификации класса как "дата-класс" используйте [атрибуты](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes).

Comment: `Как это можно сделать?` А зачем? Если пишете под .NET 5 на C# 9.0, можете использовать `record` как хранилище данных вместо `class`, и вопрос решится сам собой.

Comment: Type.GetMethods().Count() - вместе с методами он считает и свойства

Comment: Поделитесь с нами секретным знанием, а зачем это нужно? Если например я переопределил `ToString()` у класса с данными - всё сломается? И самое главное - какую именно задачу вы решаете? Быть может станет тогда понятно без километровой переписки, как решить ваш вопрос с первого раза.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, имеется следующий класс:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Используя рефлексию, посмотрим, какие у него имеются методы:

```
var t = typeof(Person);

foreach (var m in t.GetMethods())
    Console.WriteLine(m.Name);
```

Вывод:

```
get_Id
set_Id
get_Name
set_Name
GetType
ToString
Equals
GetHashCode
```

Тут четыре метода от базового класса `System.Object` и методы с префиксами `get_` и `set_` - аксессоры свойств. Нужно их отфильтровать.

```
int methodCount = t.GetMethods()
    .Where(m => !m.Name.StartsWith("get_") && !m.Name.StartsWith("set_"))
    .Count();
```

Осталось учесть количество базовых методов:

```
if (methodCount == 4)
    // класс без методов
else
    // класс имеет методы
```

Это не учитывает наличие методов-расширения.